can't mount a /dev drive - exclusively opened, but fuser and lsof don't show anything
I have a backup of my user files (docuements, etc - all of /home/jim/) on /dev/sdd2.  I want to copy (rsync) it to my new install of ubuntu 24.  If I say
sudo mount /dev/sdd2 /media/mydir
I get an error that /dev/sdd2 is exclusively mounted.  I can do
fuser /dev/sdd2   and
lsof /dev/sdd2
and neither command returns anything (literally nothing).
All of these commands were done with nautilus closed.  But I can see the files on Nautilus.
How do I mount /dev/sdd2 so that I can rsync my files?
Thanks.

"But I can see the files on Nautilus" so did you check to see if it is already mounted at /media/jim/ for example? The command findmnt /dev/sdd2 may also be helpful.
